# Gitlab-CI Docker In Docker with Dotnet Testcontainers

Tags: .net, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, testcontainers

Good afternoon, folks. I am attempting to run a Gitlab-CI pipeline on a DotNet project that utilizes the nuget package https://github.com/HofmeisterAn/dotnet-testcontainers to manage docker containers during test execution. Over the past few days, I have tried many different configuration variations, including custom docker images incorporating Dotnet and docker. However, likely due to my lack of knowledge in the CI/CD area, I have yet to get a successful build. The net result is that I cannot get all of the dockers to talk to each other appropriately. I am reaching out for any help in getting this build system setup.

Thank you.

Current Configuration:

- Docker Desktop (4.5.1) running on windows with Expose daemon enabled in the settings.
- Gitlab-Runner registered and running locally\

  ```
  [[runners]]
    name = "Siegeon Docker Runner"
    url = "https://gitlab.com/"
    token = "withheld"
    executor = "docker"
    [runners.custom_build_dir]
    [runners.cache]
      [runners.cache.s3]
      [runners.cache.gcs]
      [runners.cache.azure]
    [runners.docker]
      tls_verify = false
      image = "docker:stable"
      privileged = true
      disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
      oom_kill_disable = false
      disable_cache = false
      volumes = ["/cache"]
      shm_size = 0
  ```
- Gitlab-ci.yml

  ```
  stages:
    - tests

  test-with-coverage:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
    stage: tests
    services:
      services:
      # DinD service is required for Testcontainers
      - name: docker:dind
      command: ["--tls=false"]
    before_script:
      - docker info
    variables:
      # Instruct Docker not to start over TLS.
      DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
      # Improve performance with overlayfs.
      DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
      DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
      CONFIGURATION: "Debug"
      COVERAGE_FLAG: "XPlat Code Coverage"
      LOGGER_FLAG: "junit;LogFilePath=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/junit/junit-test-result.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"
    script:
      - 'dotnet test
              -c $CONFIGURATION
              -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR/cobertura
              --collect:"$COVERAGE_FLAG"
              --test-adapter-path:.
              --logger:"$LOGGER_FLAG"'
      - cd scripts
      - chmod +x print-dotnet-coverage.sh
      - ./print-dotnet-coverage.sh $CI_PROJECT_DIR/cobertura
    coverage: /TOTAL_COVERAGE=(\d+.\d+)/
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/cobertura/*/coverage.cobertura.xml
        - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/junit/junit-test-result.xml
      reports:
        cobertura:
          - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/cobertura/*/coverage.cobertura.xml
        junit:
          - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/junit/junit-test-result.xml
  ```

Gitlab logs

````
```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.7.0 (98daeee0)
  on Siegeon Docker Runner TdwgDJWA
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:50
Using Docker executor with image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:1a42336ff683d7dadd320ea6fe9d93a5b101474346302d23f96c9b4546cb414d 
for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:6f2ae4a5fd85ccf85cdd829057a34ace894d25d544e5e4d9f2e7109297fedf8d ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
*** WARNING: Service runner-tdwgdjwa-project-33678908-concurrent-0-82673b37ef5d9ae1-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-tdwgdjwa-project-33678908-concurrent-0-82673b37ef5d9ae1-docker-0-wait-for-service" timeout
Health check container logs:
Service container logs:
2022-03-02T17:34:46.439281600Z time="2022-03-02T17:34:46.438975100Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
2022-03-02T17:34:46.440522500Z time="2022-03-02T17:34:46.440396800Z" level=warning msg="could not change group 
/var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found"
```
````

9/27/2022 For completeness
During the initialization of build I reconfigured the docker host
[image]

Comment: 1. i think you don't need any business logic in runners configs, for example, `image = "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0"` is related to your business logic, it should only exist in `gitlab_ci.yml`. 2. you need clarify the test target, test method, which should be the same no matter you use docker or not. 3. are you really familiar with *dotnet-testcontainers*? i suppose not, please don't mix the question with two unfamiliar things (another is gitlab ci), need be more focused.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm very familiar with testcontainer and I do not understand how the container image I'm using to run the tests is business logic. Can you explain?

Comment: if your real question is about **gitlab ci**, then don't mix it with other unrelated things. not all the gitlab ci answerers are interested in *dotnet-testcontainers* even *dotnet*.

Comment: But my real question not about gitlab-ci in isolation. It is using gitlab-ci to execute a build pipleline that interacts with docker through a library.

Comment: then probably *dotnet-testcontainers*'s github issues is a better place, you should get faster resonse than here.

Comment: I think this is a valid question for the interaction and integration of multiple technologies (Gitlab-CI, Docker and testcontainers-net).

Answer (score 1):

This example did work for me when using [testcontainers-dotnet](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet) in combination with .net6.0, ef core and the gitlab pipeline. Hope it can help someone.

**Application Code to initialize Testcontainers:**

```cs
namespace Tests;

public class IntegrationTestFactory :
    WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    //mssql container definition
    private readonly Testcontainers.MsSql.MsSqlContainer _dbContainer;

    public IntegrationTestFactory()
    {
        //build container
        _dbContainer = new MsSqlBuilder()
            .WithCleanUp(true)
            .Build();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            //Remove possibly added dbcontextoptions
            var descriptor = services
                .SingleOrDefault(d => 
                    d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>));

            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                services.Remove(descriptor);
            }

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            {
                //get connection string from container
                options.UseSqlServer(_dbContainer.GetConnectionString());
            });

            // Ensure database gets created
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var context = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        });
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync() => await _dbContainer.StartAsync();

    public new async Task DisposeAsync() => await _dbContainer.StopAsync();
}
```

**gitlab-ci.yaml (test job part)**

```yaml
test_job:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
  stage: build
  only:
    - develop
    - /^feature.*$/
  services:
  - name: docker:dind
    # explicitly disable tls to avoid docker startup interruption
    command: ["--tls=false"]
  variables:
    # Instruct Testcontainers to use the daemon of DinD.
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
    # Instruct Docker not to start over TLS.
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    # Improve performance with overlayfs.
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  script:
    - dotnet restore mySolution.sln -s 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json' -s $NUGET_SOURCE
    - dotnet test src/Tests/Tests.csproj
  tags:
    - docker
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's 100% compatible, but [Testcontainers-java's example config for Gitlab](https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/gitlab_ci/) has a few differences:

Start docker with TLS disabled:

```
services:
    # explicitly disable tls to avoid docker startup interruption
    command: ["--tls=false"]
```

Also the `DOCKER_HOST` string is different:

```
# your config has DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375
DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
```

Hope with these config changes it works just like for the Testcontainers-java builds.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have updated the question with the configurations taken from the link you provided. I think the issue lies somewhere in how the containers are talking to each other during startup

Comment: From a quick look at the sources, it seems to me as if this testcontainers-net implementation does not support dynamic configuration of Docker host: https://github.com/HofmeisterAn/dotnet-testcontainers/blob/develop/src/DotNet.Testcontainers/Configurations/Unix.cs#L10 
Creating an issue in the repo might be the best approach.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome suggestion. https://github.com/HofmeisterAn/dotnet-testcontainers/blob/f25ed8705fa72c9d03eb185c41bd783db0fbb908/src/DotNet.Testcontainers/Builders/TestcontainersBuilder.cs I figured the WithDockerEndpoint configuration in the build class would allow me to set the docker host, but perhaps it is not being set correctly. I will dig into it.

Comment: Hi @Siegeon, I think I have a similar issue, have you figured it out?

Comment: They may have fixed the code base, but for now I just reconfigured the builder.